# Firefox addon for searching with different search engines

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, search, context-menu

I want to be able to right click on the selected text and, instead of *Search Google for [whatever is selected]*, I want to have a submenu that allows me to choose the search engine I want. The list of search engines has to be the **exact** list of search engines I have. I know there is such an add-on, because I've used something like this in the past, only I can't remember its name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Context Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/contextual-search/)

> Search selected text using your preferred search engines. 
>   Right-click or Shift-click on selected text to respectively launch the
>   context menu or the grid of icons. 
>   You can also perform searches using keywords in the url address bar.

[image: image1]

---

The following addons appear to have since been deleted.

[SearchWith](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2194) (no longer avaliable)

> SearchWith extension allows you to
>   search selected with various search
>   services. It adds a "Search With" sub
>   menu on the context menu (right-click
>   menu) with a configurable list of
>   search services that can be used to
>   search the highlighted text.

[image: image2]

[SmartSearch](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/188) (no longer avaliable)

> Right-click on a word or group of
>   selected words, and from the popup
>   menu, select a website. SmartSearch
>   will perform a search as though you
>   had gone to that website and entered
>   the selected words. You may add any
>   website to the menu by visiting that
>   site, right-clicking on its search
>   field, selecting "Add a Keyword for
>   this Search..." and picking a name and
>   keyword.

[image: image3]

Answer (score 0):

Another link for completeness: ["Add to Search Bar"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3682).