# How can I add "Search with Wikipedia" to my Firefox right-click menu?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox addon for searching with different search engines](https://superuser.com/questions/71341/firefox-addon-for-searching-with-different-search-engines)

By default, I can select a word/phrase, right-click and choose "`Search with Google`". I'd like a "`Search with Wikipedia`" to mimic this option, but instead of using Wikipedia's search function, I'd like to use the following search string:

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&q=wikipedia+%s

%s = word/phrase that has been selected
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Search With...` function is linked to Firefox's Search Box.

It is showing you `Search With Google` because you have Google selected for your Search Box.

If you change the search to Wikipedia (add it [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search-engines/) if you don't have it already) you will get `Search with Wikipedia` in your right click.

If you want a custom `Search With...` on right click you will need to create your own custom search plug-in, add this to Firefox and then set it as the Search Box.

A tutorials to create a custom search is [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Custom-Search-Engine-to-Firefox's-Search-Bar-(Windows-Version))